# track compiled software output without verbose?

Tags: command-line, python, compiling, output

Is there a universal way to verbose/monitor/track actions of compiled code?

Example, gui app on linux moves all files in /Downloads to Library folder according to file type.

How can I track the apps inputs? Take for example the App 'Stacer'. Ignoring the available source code and implemented verbose functions.

I searched for a while now but I feel like I'm not using the right terms. Question is too long for Quora and I'm sorry if I'm wrong here. Any suggestions where such questions get answered best?

Comment: What does `app inputs` mean? You can `strace` to see syscalls that a given app calls and their parameters.

Comment: There might be another solution if you describe the problem you are having.